# Google Guice - have the same erasure - compilation error after java upgrade from v6 to v7

Tags: java, generics, guice

I am upgrading java version from 6 to 7 for my project. It used to compile fine with java 6.

```
@Provides
VptchProvIntf provideVptchProv(NeVersion neVersion, Provider<ClVptchProv> classicProvider,      Provider<RsVptchProv> rsProvider)
{
    return (VptchProvIntf)provideForPlatform(neVersion, classicProvider, rsProvider);
}

@Provides
StsnVcnProvIntf provideVptchProv(NeVersion neVersion, Provider<ClStsnVcnProv> classicProvider, Provider<RsStsnVcnProv> rsProvider)
{
    return (StsnVcnProvIntf)provideForPlatform(neVersion, classicProvider, rsProvider);
}
```

This is snapshot from a de-compiled class. Types were not erased by compiler and code compiles fine.

But after java upgrade to version 7, this code has started giving compilation error

> error: name clash: provideVptchProv(NeVersion,Provider,Provider) and provideVptchProv(NeVersion,Provider,Provider) have the same erasure

Has Java 7 changed anything that is not allowing Guice to work.

**Note : Google Guice version is 2.0**

Do I need to update Guice or is there any workaround?

Comment: I do not see how this could have compiled with Java 6 since both methods do have the same erasure o_O

Comment: http://blog.publicobject.com/2008/11/guice-punches-erasure-in-face.html - google provides guice library to avoid that

Comment: It is not a guice problem. This code can't compile with any version of java. The methods have same the type erasure. You could try it again with java 6 and it will not compile.

Comment: The code snippet is from de-compiled class, and it has not removed types. And it compiles with java 6.

Comment: @Batty, there is some misunderstanding here because there is **no way** Java compiler could have accepted such methods. They do have the same erasure, and this is a fundamental limitation of the JVM itself - disallow overloaded methods with the same erasure. Guice does not have anything to do with it. Anyway, in order to resolve this, you can just rename one of the overloads because `@Provides` method names do not have any meaning for Guice, so they can be arbitrary.

Comment: @VladimirMatveev This was a java 5/6 bug that got fixed in 7.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The Java 5 and 6 compilers had a bug that would accept your methods, because they considered the signature to include the return type in the check.

In Java 7, methods cannot have the same erased signatures, regardless of their return types.  See [this](http://notatube.blogspot.ca/2010/07/interesting-change-to-method-signature.html) blog post and [this](http://bugs.java.com/view_bug.do?bug_id=6182950) bug report.

In your case, the answer is to rename one of your methods.